# Bootstrap text between floats

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with 3 object in one row there is text between two images on the desktop it show this http://www.part.lt/img/d3aabc6dea1cafd939b9cda8152403a5633.jpg on mobile looks great, i need solution any help ?

my code:

```
<div class="pull-left hidden-xs">
    <img src="images/head_window.png" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="header_title">
    <h2 class="align-right">åpnes i<br/>
          eller<br/>
          åpne ut
    </h2>
</div>
<div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
    <img src="images/head_window2.png" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

css

```
.header_title {
    margin:90px auto 0px; 
    width: 32%; 
    text-align: center;  
    padding: 0px; 
 }
.header_title h2 {
    font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif; 
    font-size: 73px;
    color: #004657; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add columns since you using boostrap.

```
 <div class="col-sm-5">
      <div class="pull-left hidden-xs">
        <img src="images/head_window.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="header_title">
        <h2 class="align-right">åpnes eller åpne ut</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
        <img src="images/head_window2.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: problem that first image smaller than other appears in this case..
col-sm-6 forboth images should be fine but after that happpens situation i posted in image

Comment: You have 12 columns so, you can't set 6 + 2 + 6.

Comment: I know that, so i need other solution :))